# MYSQL Error Code: 1064 in the view

Tags: mysql

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT OUTER JOIN dw_fact_claim ON dw_fact_claim.patient_id = dw_snf.patient_id
 ' at line 13
```

my query is:

```
CREATE VIEW DW_SNF
AS 
 SELECT
                   REL , 
                   PATIENT_ID , 
                   MIN( CLM_FROM_DT )AS clm_from_dt , 
                   MAX( clm_THRU_dt )AS clm_THRU_dT
            FROM dw_SNF
            WHERE REL <> ''
            GROUP BY
                     REL , 
                     PATIENT_ID 
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN dw_fact_claim ON dw_fact_claim.patient_id = dw_snf.patient_id
                                              AND dw_fact_claim.CLM_FROM_DT >= dw_SNF.clm_from_dt
                                              AND dw_fact_claim.CLM_THRU_DT <= dw_SNF.clm_thru_dt
                                              AND dw_fact_claim.TYPE_OF_CLAIM NOT LIKE '%snf%'
            WHERE dw_SNF.rel <> ''
            GROUP BY
                     rel  ON SUMMARY.REL = SNF_BASE.REL 
          INNER JOIN dw_VIEW_dim_patient_FLAG AS DW_DIM_PATIENT ON dw_dim_patient.patient_id = dw_snf.patient_id
          INNER JOIN DW_VIEW_JH_ACG_CONDENSED dw_jh_acg ON dw_jh_acg.patient_id = dw_dim_patient.patient_id
     WHERE SNF_EPISODE_ID <> '';
```

Comment: Have a look at the documentation about the order of keywords in (My)SQL.

Comment: You can not have a `LEFT JOIN` in a `Group by` clause. `LEFT JOIN` belongs to `FROM`

Comment: Thank you Sirko and Jens.Its my mistake to use where clause before join condition.

Answer (score 0):

I have used where clause before left outer join,that's the error was and after using where condition at the end of join conditions i have created view successfully.We can not have JOIN in Group by clause.